# how to serialize a class who contains a HashMap as attribut with Gson? also deserialize?

Tags: java, json, serialization, hashmap, gson

I wanted to serialize a class who contains a HashMap and that hHashHap has a class key. but it goes wrong.

```
    public class Buyer {
        private long wallet;
        private HashMap<Discount, Integer> discountCodes;
    }
```

when I use toJson method

```
"discountCodes":{"model.Discount@18769467":1,"model.Discount@1cf4f579":2}
```

it serialized like this so in deserializing cause ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 34 path $[0].discountCodes.
```

I mean how to **convert an object of Buyer** to json not converting HashMap

Answer (score 0):

1. Serialize HashMap containing generic types to JSON

```
HashMap<Integer, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

employeeMap.put(1, new Employee(1l, "Alex", LocalDate.of(1990, 01, 01)));
employeeMap.put(2, new Employee(2l, "Bob", LocalDate.of(1990, 02, 01)));

//Deep clone
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(employeeMap);
```

Generated json:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alex",
    "dob": {
      "year": 1990,
      "month": 1,
      "day": 1
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bob",
    "dob": {
      "year": 1990,
      "month": 2,
      "day": 1
    }
  }
}
```

2. Convert JSON to HashMap containing custom objects

```
        HashMap<Integer, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

        employeeMap.put(1, new Employee(1l, "Alex", LocalDate.of(1990, 01, 01)));
        employeeMap.put(2, new Employee(2l, "Bob", LocalDate.of(1990, 02, 01)));

        //Deep clone
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(employeeMap);

        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, Employee>>(){}.getType();
        HashMap<Integer, Employee> clonedMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```